# How to update the view from a activity from a class

Tags: android

So I need to update two views if the user is currently on those views when a notification that stores data is received. I update the views onResume and such but if the user is on one of the pages and gets data it will not update and I do not know how I can update the view as it would require context and I cannot figure out how to transfer context or even update the Linear layout without calling in these functions in the class that contains the layout and view. Any help to accomplish this is greatly appreciated.
EDIT: The calss that I am using is not ordinary it is the GCMIntentClass that receives messages. That's why i need to handle the data and when it gets this data update the layout of the activity that the user is in.

Comment: Register the views to receive an intent and broadcast it when you get a gcm notification. As simple as that

Comment: Do you think you could tell me how I would do that? I am still new to GCM

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `Context` via the constructor of the class that is not an Activity. For example:

```
public MyClass(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
}
```

And then use the `Context` to do whatever you want with the `View`

Comment: That will be helpful in other instances but what I realize now that I should have mentioned is that this class is a GCMIntentService. Meaning that it runs in the background and receives the messages that are sent from GCM. I never have to contruct this class because when added into the manifest it links with broadcast receiver and other classes for construction.

Comment: `GCMIntentSevice` provides a `Context` on nearly all methods.

Comment: How would I access this context that GCM provides?